# Magento2 How can we add bundle option price in product options in Order REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I need to add the bundle option price to the list of bundle options data. I need to add this in the Orders REST API

After options_qty in the below screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how to create a plugin to include this information but looking at the database itself I see you can find that info under
sales_order_item.product_options

The bundle options don't show the full values stored while querying the API by default, take a look at the extension attributes I'm getting:
[image]